# Do you need fertiliser for rockwool starter cubes?

Tags: hydroponic

I want to start some seedlings in rockwool cubes. Eventually I want to start some hydroponics plants. Im getting conflicting messages on the internet in regards to whether you should add liquid fertiliser to the rockwool when you first hydrate them. Is it required for the seeds to germinate or does the seed have all that is required to sprout in the seed?

Im using EHG grow formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple tap water for germinating seeds. Seeds are self containing packets and have all the necessary nutrients to start the root system and probably first set of real leaves. (The one that shows up first are not real leaves, they are seed leaves and are of generally different shape)

if you want your seedlings to grow up quite a bit in it's first growing media, you can use a nutrient solution of 100-200 TDS. Do not use stronger nutrient solution as it will burn out the tender seedling. This too is suggested only after the real leaves appear.